# Java commons-csv: QuoteMode.MINIMAL quotes too much?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons, quoting

I'm using Java `org.apache.commons.csv` (version 1.8) with quote mode [MINIMAL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html#MINIMAL) to write a CSV file.

I'm wondering if the following quoting behaviour is expected with respect to quoting the cell `"foo bar   "`:

```
csvPrinter.printRecord("eggs", "foo bar   ", "spam");
```

gives in output:

```
eggs,"foo bar   ",spam
```

My expectation is that the double quotes shouldn't be there with quote mode *MINIMAL*.

Minimal example here:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.apache.commons.csv.QuoteMode;

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.EXCEL
            .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL);

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, csvFormat);
    csvPrinter.printRecord("eggs", "foo bar   ", "spam");
    csvPrinter.flush();
    csvPrinter.close();
}
```

---

For comparison, the same record printed with Python pandas does not contain quotes:

```
import pandas
import sys
import csv

df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': ['eggs'], 'b': ['foo bar  '], 'c': ['spam']})
df.to_csv(sys.stdout, quoting= csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

,a,b,c
0,eggs,foo bar  ,spam       <<< No quotes!
```

Am I missing something...?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `CSVFormat` [code](https://github.com/apache/commons-csv/blob/660f7c9f853092ec8abf5d6c81d260e3c80c2194/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.java), quotes are added when the cell ends with a space or any character with a lower numeric value i.e. tab or newline

```
static final char SP = ' ';
...
case MINIMAL:
...
if (!quote) {
    pos = end - 1;
    c = value.charAt(pos);
    // Some other chars at the end caused the parser to fail, so for now
    // encapsulate if we end in anything less than ' '
    if (c <= SP) {
        quote = true;
    }
}
```

The:

> // Some other chars at the end caused the parser to fail, so for now
>   // encapsulate if we end in anything less than ' '

comment is somewhat cryptic so I don't know if the bug is in the code or in the documentation which doesn't say that [QuoteMode.MINIMAL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html#MINIMAL) does that:

> Quotes fields which contain special characters such as a the field delimiter, quote character or any of the characters in the line separator string.

As to pandas doing something different it doesn't mean much, there is no csv standard and quoting a cell that ends with a space when your goal is to quote as little as possible might be the correct thing to do.